# Converting a list of lists into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a function that first generates a list of vectors (generated by using lapply), and then cbinds it to a column vector. I thought this would produce a dataframe. However, it produces a list of lists.

The cbind function isn't working as I thought it would.

Here's a small example of what the function is generating

```
col_test <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2)
lst_test <- list(c(1, 2 , 3), c(2, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 2), c(1, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 1))
a_df <- cbind(col_test, lst_test)
```

Typing

```
> a_df[1,]
```

gives the output

```
$`col_test`
[1] 1

$lst_test
[1] 1 2 3
```

I'd like the data frame to be

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1    1    2    3

[2,] 2    2    2    2

[3,] 1    1    1    2

[4,] 1    1    2    2

[5,] 2    1    1    1
```

How do I get it into this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.frame(col_test,t(as.data.frame(lst_test)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind, Map(c, col_test, lst_test))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    2    3
#[2,]    2    2    2    2
#[3,]    1    1    1    2
#[4,]    1    1    2    2
#[5,]    2    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
col_test <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2)
lst_test <- list(c(1, 2 , 3), c(2, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 2), c(1, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 1))
```

name the sublists so we can use bind_rows

```
names(lst_test) <- 1:length(lst_test)   
lst_test1 <- bind_rows(lst_test)
```

the bind_rows function binds by cols in this case so we need to pivot it

```
lst_test_pivot <- t(lst_test1)
```

but this gives us a matrix, so we need to cast it back to a dataframe

```
lst_test_pivot_df <- as.data.frame(lst_test_pivot)
```

now it works as

```
cbind(col_test, lst_test_pivot_df)
```

now produces

```
  col_test V1 V2 V3
1        1  1  2  3
2        2  2  2  2
3        1  1  1  2
4        1  1  2  2
5        2  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to generate a df from the answer by xenopus, but the row names were weird. So this answer helped me get around that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Note that we are using `do.call` so that the individual elements of `lst_test` are sent as parameters to `cbind`, which prevents `cbind` from creating a list-of-lists. `t` is used to transpose the resulting matrix to your preferred orientation, and finally, one more `cbind` with `col_test` inserts that data as well.

```
library(tidyverse)

mat.new <- do.call(cbind, lst_test) %>% 
  t %>% 
  cbind(col_test, .) %>% 
  unname

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    3
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    1    1    1    2
[4,]    1    1    2    2
[5,]    2    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thank You. I chose to use the code in the answer by xenopus, because it's a little more intuitive for me. But I will keep this in mind for future reference.